# Can't install certain Python Modules with pip

Tags: python, pip

I already have pip added to path, but when i try to install certain modules, this happens:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement (module name)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for (module name)
```

This always happens when i try to install Time or OpenCV, what can i do?

Comment: please add more details like which package with version, your OS and python version

Comment: this is the command to install opencv ```pip install opencv-python```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the module names at https://pypi.org

```
pip install opencv-python
```

https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/

Answer (score 0):

may be  your  packagename is wrong
opencv   is   pip install opencv-python